# Angular rich text editor max length validation

Tags: angular, rich-text-editor, html-editor, ngx-quill, kolkov-editor

I need to set the max length of Angular Editor. I have tried so many ways but was not able to set the maxlength.

```
 <angular-editor
    [(ngModel)]="htmlContent"
    [config]="config"
    maxlength="10"></angular-editor>
```

I have tried the below editors.

- kolkov/angular-editor
- ngx-quill
- p-editor

Please help me to solve the maxlength validations.

**Or**

Suggest me the other editor with minlength and maxlength validation options.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-editor-wysiwyg-afbpk1?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: It does not look like from the documentation that maxlength and minlength validations are supported out of the box with Angular-Editor...You could roll your own code on keyup event to track the length of text entered by user... validate that

Comment: In general frontend length validation is reflect the backend validator. So one option is to remove HTML tags and set a manual validator flash show/false.